# Given a complex number set, how do you prove which set is it in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ is it true that:
$|a| < |b|$ implies $|a|^{2} < |b|^{2}$
I want to use this to build sets of points in the complex plane since I have things like:
$$|z-1| < |z|$$
So I want to apply power to both sides and then change $z = x+iy$ to discover what the set is in terms of the real coordinates.

Is it useful?

Which other strategies do you recommend in order to discover what the set is in terms of the real coordinates?

Comment: Can you please clarify what the second part of the question is asking?

Answer (score 0):

The map $x\mapsto x^2$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$: since $\lvert z\rvert\in[0,\infty)$, we indeed have that $\lvert a\rvert<\lvert b\rvert$ if and only if $\lvert a\rvert^2<\lvert b\rvert^2$.

This strategy is fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that, as both are nonnegative real numbers, $\:|z-1|<|z|\iff |z-1|^2<|z|^2$.

However it is much simpler to solve  than what you want to undertake,  as $|z|^2=z\bar z$: you obtain instantly that
$$|z-1|<|z|\iff\iff(z-1)(\bar z -1)<z\bar z\iff z+\bar z=2\operatorname{Re}z>1$$
so the set is simply the half-plane $\operatorname{Re}z>\frac 12$.

*Note*: this answer was geometrically obvious, as the inequation $|z-1|>|1|$ means the image of $z$ in the complex plane is closer from the origin than from the real point $1$ on the real axis, so by a med-school argument, the image of $z$ belongs to the half-plane on the right of the perpendicular bisector of the segment $[0,1]$ on the real axis.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, $|z-1| < |z|$ means that the distance from $z$ to the point $(1,0) $ is less than its distance to $(0,0)$, which covers the half plane to the right of $x=\frac12$.